# Merging two columns with values from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have similar table

[image]

How can i merge these two tables ? There are other columns, but these are the same.

How can i fill Table1 with values of Table2 or merge these tables ?
In Table2 is only 1 customer.

So the result table will have all customers with their values (Table1 will have Customer4 with Sales 50).

Thank you.

Comment: codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the table do

```
update t1
set t1.sales = t2.sales
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.customername = t2.customername
```

and as a select use

```
select t1.customername, 
       coalesce(t1.sales, t2.sales) as sales,
       t1.date,
       t1.variable1
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.customername = t2.customername
```

Comment: That will do the trick, thank you. But it is possible to do this in select also ? Some IFNULL with condition SubQuery i dont know ? :_)